# How to write json to Google Cloud Driver

Tags: python, django, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using django for logging. Here is what I have so far:

```
from google.cloud import logging
client = logging.Client.from_service_account_json('file.json')
client.setup_logging()

LOGGING = {

 'version': 1,


 'handlers': {

    'stackdriver': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
        'client': client,
    },
  },

 'loggers': {
    'app': {
        'handlers': ['stackdriver'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
  }

}
```

And here is how it shows up in Google Stackdriver:

[image]

Is there a way to actually add additional key/value fields instead of just having the json message be formatted as text? Can any fields be added except for the "message". How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by enabling structured logging, see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging.

Specifically, you'd have to [write your own parser](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#writing_your_own_parser) that knows know to parse the log message you're emitting from Python.

Comment: thanks for this response, I'll begin working on adding that in. WOuld you be able to show a super brief example of how this would be done in python with writing/using your own parser?

Comment: I'd be happy to, could you update your question to include an example of what you'd like the structured log to look like?

Comment: @David542 Are you able to update your question to include an example?